# IOS code show this error:" Expected declaration ", I don't know why?

Tags: swift4

```
let imageViewSaoYiSao = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"saoyisao.PNG"))
imageViewSaoYiSao.frame = CGRect(x:325, y:0, width:50, height:60)
self.view.addSubview(imageViewSaoYiSao)
```

code like this, I Think all thing is ok, but, show  this error, I don't know why. thank you for your time.

Comment: there is no compile error in that code.please explain more

Comment: Where do you add this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let imageViewSaoYiSao = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "YourImageName"))
imageViewSaoYiSao.frame = CGRect(x:325, y:0, width:50, height:60)
self.view.addSubview(imageViewSaoYiSao)
```